# Rails: how to save into two tables from one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to insert some values into another table during sign up. This is what I have tried so far.

The two tables are `employees` and `organizations`. This is the form that I am currently using:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:id => "example-advanced-form"}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Account</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <%= f.label :email %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email, :id => "email-2", :class => "required email" %>
        <%= f.label :password %><br>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :id => "password-2", :class => "required" %>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :name => "confirm", :id => "confirm-2", :class => "required" %>
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </fieldset>

    <h3>Profile</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profile Information</legend>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">

        <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, :id => "name-2", :class => "required" %>
        <%= f.label :middle_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :middle_name, :id => "surname-2", :class => "required" %>
        <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, :id => "surname-2", :class => "required" %>
        <label>Designation</label><br>
        <select class="required">
          <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
          <option value="Tester">Tester</option>
          <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <%= f.fields_for :organisation do |o| %>
          <%= o.label :org_name %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :org_name, :id => "name-2", :class => "required" %>
          <label>organisation Business Type</label><br>
          <select class="required">
            <option value="Business">Business</option>
            <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
            <option value="IT">IT</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select><br>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label>Number Of Employees</label><br>
          <select class="required">
            <option value="0-10">0-10</option>
            <option value="10-50">10-50</option>
            <option value="50-100">50-100</option>
            <option value="100-500">100-500</option>
            <option value="500-1000">500-1000</option>
            <option value="1000 above">1000 above</option>
          </select><br>
          <%= o.label :address %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :address, :id => "address-2", :class => "required" %>
          <%= o.label :city %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :city, :class => "required" %>
          <%= o.label :state %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :state, :class => "required" %>
          <%= o.label :country %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :country, :class => "required" %>
          <%= o.label :email_id %><br>
          <%= o.text_field :email_id, :id => "email-2", :class => "required email" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>

    <h3>Finish</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>

        <p>We have sent you a mail for Activation of your Account. Kindly Activate your through the mail. If you haven't received any mail, please click </p>
        <%= link_to "here" %>
    </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

The form items within below block

```
<%= f.fields_for :organisation do |o| %>
<% end %>
```

are not visible in the browser. And also the values are not stored in the database.

Here are the models and view controllers.

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_employee!
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.build_organisation
  end

  def edit
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      flash[:notice] = "Employee was successfully created"
      redirect_to employees_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Employee was not created"
    end
  end

  def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    if @employee.update(employee_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Employee was successfully updated"
      redirect_to employees_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @employee.destroy

    redirect_to employees_path
  end

  private
  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:employee_id, :org_id, :role_id, :first_name, :last_name, :middle_name, :dob, :gender, :email_id, :blood_group, :join_date, :left_date, :left_reason, :referred_by, :job_code, :department_code, :encrypted_password, :is_admin, :is_activated, :remarks, :status, :created_by, :updated_by,organisation_attributes: [:org_name,:country,:state,:city,:address,:email_id])
  end

end


class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @organisations = Organisation.all
  end

  def show
    @org = Organisation.find(params[:id])
    @clients = Client.where(org_id: @org.org_id)
  end
end


class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :organisation
  belongs_to :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisation
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end


class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clients
  has_many :employees
end
```

Comment: What do you want to save in different tables ? You can just split the forms data in your controller when you receive it all.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna i want to save the organization's details during sign up

Comment: @Flip can you help me with this?